# Hi, I've been trying to validate the pie chart using the Cypress automation testing tool. But I couldn’t find the solution to verify the pie chart

Tags: cypress

1. I'm trying to validate the pie chart using cypress
2. But I'm unable to select or click on the pie chart
3. I couldn’t find any plugin in the cypress doucment
4. I wnat to know, is any possible to validate the pie chart in cypress

I tried to click or select the pie chart. But I couldn’t able to do it

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my query

Refer to this link:
https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/svg-example.html

```
// get the SVG element, just like any DOM element
cy.get('svg')
  .should('have.attr', 'width', '90')
  .and('have.attr', 'height', '90')
  // yields the original SVG element
  // after confirming its attributes, find
  // the child <path fill="none"> element
  // and confirm its attributes
  .find('path[fill=none]')
  .should('have.attr', 'stroke-linejoin', 'bevel')
  .wait(1000) // for clarity
  // change the color of the sibling "path" before it
  .prev()
  .invoke('attr', 'fill', 'red')
```